# Need to be able to Insert/Delete New Groups in openfire via HTTP or MySQL

Tags: mysql, openfire

I know how to insert a new group via MySQL, and it works, to a degree. The problem is that the database changes are not loaded into memory if you insert the group manually. Sending a HUP signal to the process does work, but it is kludgy and a hack. I desire elegance :)

What I am looking to do, if possible is to make changes (additions/deletions/changes) to a group via MySQL, and then send an HTTP request to the openfire server to read the new changes.  Or in the alternative, add/delete/modify groups similar to how the *User Service* works.

If anyone can help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Openfire is shipped with a web interface in JSP. You should try to look at how they're doing it in their web app. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that if sending a HUP signal works for you, then that's actually quite a simple, elegant and efficient way to get Openfire to read your new group, particularly if you do it with the following command on the Openfire server (and assuming it's running a Linux/Unix OS):

```
pkill -f -HUP openfire
```

If you still want to send an HTTP request to prompt Openfire to re-read the groups, the following Python script should do the job. It is targeted at Openfire 3.8.2, and depends on Python's mechanize library, which in Ubuntu is installed with the **python-mechanize** package.  The script logs into the Openfire server, pulls up the Cache Summary page, selects the Group and Group Metadata Cache options, enables the submit button and then submits the form to clear those two caches.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mechanize
import cookielib

# Customize to suit your setup
of_host = 'http://openfire.server:9090'
of_user = 'admin_username'
of_pass = 'admin_password'

# Initialize browser and cookie jar
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_cookiejar(cookielib.LWPCookieJar())

# Log into Openfire server
br.open(of_host + '/login.jsp')
br.select_form('loginForm')
br.form['username'] = of_user
br.form['password'] = of_pass
br.submit()

# Select which cache items to clear in the Cache Summary page
# On my server, 13 is Group and 14 is Group Metadata Cache
br.open(of_host + '/system-cache.jsp')
br.select_form('cacheForm')
br.form['cacheID'] = ['13','14']

# Activate the submit button and submit the form
c = br.form.find_control('clear')
c.readonly = False
c.disabled = False
r = br.submit()

# Uncomment the following line if you want to view results
#print r.read()
```

Comment: Brian, thank you for your reply - that definitely gives me some ideas on how to handle it. Is there a similar module that you know of that would give the same functionality in either PHP or Perl?

Comment: Well, there is Perl's WWW::Mechanize module that is comparable to python-mechanize. I haven't looked into anything similar for PHP though.

Comment: Thank you very much, Brian -- answer accepted, bounty awarded!